# How to pass selected checkboxes ID values from view to the controller

Tags: html, spring-boot

I am a newbie to spring boot and thymeleaf,

I have a list of books ina table with checkboxes, I am not sure how to pass selected booksId s from the view to the controller and use them by the borrow or Return bttons? could you please help?

Here is my Html file https://wtools.io/paste-code/b5g4
and this is the relevant part from my bookService implementation :

```
    public void borrowBook(String userEmail, String bookIds, Model model) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(books)) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(userEmail);
        List<String> requestedBooks = getRequestedBookIds(bookIds);
        List<Book> borrowedBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Book> invalidBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Book book : books) {
            if (requestedBooks.contains(book.getId()) && !book.isBorrowed() && user != null) {
                book.setBorrowed(true);
                book.setBorrowedBy(user.getFirstName());
                borrowedBooks.add(book);
                model.addAttribute("bookStatus", "Book BOrrowed By " + user.getFirstName());
            } else {
                invalidBooks.add(book);
                model.addAttribute("bookStatus", "No Books are available");
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("inValidBooks", invalidBooks);
        model.addAttribute("bookList", borrowedBooks);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<String> getRequestedBookIds(String bookIds) {
    List<String> requestedBookIds = null;
    try {
        requestedBookIds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(bookIds, ArrayList.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(requestedBookIds) ? requestedBookIds : new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and this is from the controller:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/available", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getAvailableFreeBooks(Model model) {
    List<Book> availableBooks= bookService.getAllAvailaBooks();
    model.addAttribute("listBooks", availableBooks);
    return "available_books";
}
```

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K2BRDNC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html you would probably:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{requestedBooks}" value="${book.getId}">
```

- omit the id (if you don't need it).
- use `th:field` (instead of `name`).
- set `value` to the id of the current book.

In your controller: `requestedBooks` (`@ModelAttribute("requestedBooks") List<String> requestedBooks`) will (should) contain all **checked** book ids.

Ref: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#checkbox-fields

---

A sample repository:

https://github.com/xerx593/soq67602860

### Uppdate:

To process the checkboxes client-sided (jquery),
you can obtain an array of ids like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnBorrow").click(function() {
       var reqBookIds = new Array();
       $('input[name="requestedBooks"]:checked').each(function() {
         reqBookIds .push(this.value);
       });
       alert("Number of selected Books: "+reqBookIds .length+"\n"+"And, they are: "+reqBookIds);
       // do stuff with reqBookIds ...
    )};
  }); 
</script>
```

With the mentioned `<input type="checkbox" .../>` (consider that `<input/>` should be inside a `<form/>`!!) and a button like:

```
<button id="btnBorrow">Borrow</button>
```

..the `userEmail` must come from client side???

Comment: Thank you, could you please help me writting the controller requestedBooks part?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/xerx593/soq67602860), dear .. i did a simple sample! ;)

Comment: The  borrow button is still not functional